# need help in primary key and foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

I need help in auto populating the primary key values in foreign key table while inserting data in foreign key table. For Example: I have created table:

```
create table Patient
(
PatientId int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
FirstName varchar(50),
SurName varchar(50),
Gender char(20),
)
```

Say 5 rows are there in this `Patient` Table:
Say First Row value is: `1, Priya, Kumari, Female`

I have created the `Guardians` Table:

```
create table Guardians
(
GuardiansId int identity(1,1) primary key,
PatientId int foreign key references Patient(PatientId),
FirstName varchar(50),
SurName varchar(50),
Gender char(20),
RelationToPatient varchar(50),
)
```

In this table Insert operations are like this:

```
insert into Guardians(FirstName, SurName, Gender,RelationToPatient)values('Sumit','Kumar','Male','Wife')
```

While selecting the Guardians Table PatientId showing `NULL` values: My query is while inserting the values in `Guardians` Table `PatientId` should be auto Populated which will come from `Patient` Table...

2. My second problem is: How to create the Identity  column as `varchar`. For example: suppose I want to increment my `Guardians` Table with '`GRD0001', 'GRD0002', 'GRD0003'` like this...

Thanks,
S.D

Comment: Nitpick... how many genders do you have?  `0` for female and `1` for male should suffice?

Comment: @Buckwad: hey, some people don't like to be pigeonholed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear - what exactly do you want to do??

When you insert something into the `Guardians` table, you want to automatically also insert it into the `Patients` table? I don't quite follow. Can you make a complete example, maybe??

If you need to capture the insert IDENTITY value from the `Patient` table, do this:

```
DECLARE @NewPatientID INT

INSERT INTO dbo.Patient(fields) VALUES(.......)

SET @NewPatientID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.Guardians(PatientId, ......) VALUES(@NewPatientID, ......)
```

As for your second question: leave you `GuardiansId` IDENTITY as it is (only an INT column can be an IDENTITY and you want to keep that - trust me!) and add a computed column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Guardians
  ADD GuardianIDWithPrefix AS 
    'GDR' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(GuardiansId AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) PERSISTED
```

Since it's a **PERSISTED** field, you can even index on it and use it like a normal field in every respect.

That should do the trick!